# SQL-Query to decrypt vlaues encrypted by PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

Is there an SQL command for MySQL in order to decrypt values which were encrypted by hibernate using the algorithm PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES?

Comment: i believe hibernates PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES is the same as MySQL's `DES_DECRYPT` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_des-decrypt ) and `DES_ENCRYPT` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_des-encrypt ) functions..You also might need to use MySQL's md5 function.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, no, sorry but there is no such thing in SQL as a native function.

you might like to take a look on this site to create your Frankenstein functions to resolve that 
https://www.example-code.com/sql/encryption.asp

I hope it helps!

Comment: "Ouch, no, sorry but there is no such thing in SQL as a native function." MySQL supports Triple-DES algorithm with (DES_DECRYPT and DES_ENCRYPT) but iám not sure if it's the same as hibernate's PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES algorithm.. Besides the linked article is about SQL server not MySQL

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will give it a try and see if I can figgure out something.